# SqlPackage.exe: Error SQL0: Required contributor with id 'id' could not be loaded

Tags: sql

while trying to build dacpac using sqlpackage.exe, we are getting the following error

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServicesException: An error occurred during deployment plan generation. Deployment cannot continue.
Error SQL0: Required contributor with id 'BcDevKit.DeploymentContributors.DacMacroSqlDeploymentContributor' could not be loaded.
```

The above error can be fixed if I copy the contributors from 
    `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\150\Extensions`

to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DAC\bin\Extensions`

I want sqlpackage to search for contributors only in Visual Studio directory. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

I have figured the answer on my own and wanted to help someone like me.

So, the problem is I was referencing sqlpackage.exe from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DAC\bin` directory, that is why it was looking for the contributor in it's sub-directory `\Extensions`.

I was looking around in Visual Studio installation directory and found the sqlpackage.exe in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\150` directory, updated the path in environment variables and it worked.